# Getting IIS Manager Application Pool Defaults from the command line

Tags: command-line-interface, iis

I was tasked to confirm settings on some (many many) servers. One thing I was told to do was to go in to Server Manager, Roles, Web Server (IIS), Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager and then under Connections select the server's Application Pool and then Set Application Pool Defaults to check under:

- "(General)" the ".NET Framework Version", "Enable 32 bit applications" and "Managed Pipeline" settings.
- "Process Model" check "Identity", "Idle Time-out" and "Load User Profile" settings.
- "Rapid Fail Protection" check "Maximum Failures"
- "Recycling" check "Regular Time Interval" and "Specific Times" settings.

I started messing around with doing:

```
C:\> appcmd /text:* list config /section:system.applicationHost/applicationPools
```

I notice under `[applicationPoolDefaults]` where it has `name=""` it has I think all I need to find, but it gets to an `[add]` section with a different `name="..."` after which information is repeated. Would I only need to grab the first section? Is there any way to reutrn a specific line through `appcmd` itself?

Also, under "Recycling" I couldn't clearly identify what `Regular Time Interval (minutes)` refers to as "[PeriodicRestart]" has 3 values with "0" there: memory, privateMemory and requests. I don't think it could be `privateMemory` or requests so would it then be "memory" or am I totally off base?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start looking at "reference" on iis.net

Look here [Application Pool Defaults](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/applicationpooldefaults), then look for each element/attribute you need to configure, they usually have appcmd based example at the bottom. It'll be just a matter of combining of all the settings into a series of appcmd commands.